# Datasource url for jqxgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jqxgrid in view as follows

```js
var source =
              {
                  datatype: "json",
                  datafields: [
                       { name: 'MailBoxID', type: 'string' },
                       { name: 'TOName', type: 'string' },
                       { name: 'Subject', type: 'string' },
                       { name: 'DateCreated', type: 'date' }
                   ],
                  url: "/Mailman/Results/"                          
                     
                  };
                var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
                var imagerenderer = function (row, datafield, value) {
                    return '<img style="margin-left: 5px;"  src="/Images/props.gif' + value + '"/>';
                }
                // initialize jqxGrid
                $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
                    {
                        width: 700,
                        height:310,
                        source: dataAdapter,
                        pageable: true,
                        columns: [
                            { text: '', datafield: 'Image', cellsrenderer: imagerenderer },
                            { text: "To", datafield: "TOName", width: 289 },
                            { text: "Subject", datafield: "Subject", width: 281 },
                            { text: "Date", datafield: "DateCreated", cellsformat: 'M/d/yyyy', width: 100 }
                        ]
                    });
            });
        });
```

and controller methods as follows

```
public ActionResult Result()
{                   
    Result res = new Result();
    List<Result> list = new List<Result>();
    list = res.GetResults();
    return View(list);             
}
```

I would like to know how to give the url for jqxgrid when the data source url is something like "mailman/results?status=N" instead of "mailman/results". Here status can be N,W,R etc depending on the web browser url.

Comment: Can you post some detail about what the URL will look like for `N, W, R` etc?

Comment: The url looks like http://localhost:49295/Mailman/Result?status=W or http://localhost:49295/Mailman/Result?status=N etc

Comment: you have to return data in json format not in view.